# Problem regarding existence of a function.

Tags: real-analysis, limits, functions, continuity

Let $f:[0,1]\to \mathbb{R}$ be function satisfying, $$\lim_{x\to a}f(x)= ∞, \forall a\in [0,1].$$ Thus such a function exists?

Comment: $f(x) = \infty$ except at finitely many points.

Comment: I am beginner in real analysis. Please elaborate your thoughts.

Comment: @DougM Problem: $\infty \notin \Bbb{R}$.

Comment: @SKRABIULISLAM Actually, it's required on this site for you to elaborate your thoughts first. You say you're a beginner in real analysis, but I'm sure you know some theorems. What have you been learning about? Which tools do you have at your disposal?

Comment: @Prof.Sonku For example, are you familiar with Baire Category Theorem?

Comment: @Theo Bendit Yes I know that theorem. Also I Know that set of point of discontinuity is Countable union of closed set. But in that case point of infinite discontinuity set if countable union of closed set.

Comment: @TheoBendit Indeed, I was aware of that, but I still thought it was helpful to think about what the implications of the statement.

Comment: @Prof.Sonku Try using the BCT. If such a function $f$ existed, show that the set $A_m = \{ x \in [0, 1] : |f(x)| \le m\}$ is nowhere dense.

Comment: @Theo Bendit thanks. I got it.

Answer (score 0):

Lets partition the domain such that we have some $A$ that is a subset of the interval that is the domain of our function.

Suppose $f(x) = p$ when $x\in A$ and $f(x) = q$ when $x\notin A$

If $A$ has finitely many points, then for all $a \in A$

$\lim_\limits{x\to a} = q$

It can't be $p$ because there exists a neighborhood around $a$ such that for all $x$ in the neighborhood (excluding $a$)  $f(x) = b$

But if there are infinitely many points, then there exists some $a\in A$ such that every neighborhood of $a$ will have at least one more point in $A$ that is arbitrarily close to $a.$

Either the function is continuous at $a$ and $\lim_\limits{x\to a} = p$ or it is not and the limit does not exist.

Now, that we have that $f(x) = \infty$  for some subset of $[0,1]$ and infinty is not a real number, no such function exists such that $f:[0,1]\to \mathbb R$